# Can I change the passed value inside function?

Tags: javascript

I want to transfer variable using `function()`, but I am not sure if I am able to put variable inside of variable

I tried to put variable inside variable like this `var toStore = myVariable`

```
var myText = "Hi";

changeMyText(myText);


function changeMyText(variableToUse) {
    variableToUse = "Hello World";
    console.log(myText);
}
```

It does not change the content of variable `myText`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the argument you pass to function is `pass by value` this means that even when you change the argument value it doesn't reflect to actual value...

Here, from [w3Schools - JavaScript Function Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

> ## Arguments are Passed by Value
>
> The parameters, in a function call, are the function's arguments.
>
> JavaScript arguments are passed by value: The function only gets to
> know the values, not the argument's locations.
>
> If a function changes an argument's value, it does not change the
> parameter's original value.
>
> **Changes to arguments are not visible (reflected) outside the function.**
>
> ---
>
> ## Objects are Passed by Reference
>
> In JavaScript, object references are values.
>
> Because of this, objects will behave like they are passed by
> reference:
>
> If a function changes an object property, it changes the original
> value.
>
> **Changes to object properties are visible (reflected) outside the
> function**

---

This from [mdn - function deceleration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_declarations) | Thanks @Ivar

> Primitive parameters (such as a number) are passed to functions by value; the value is >passed to the function, but if the function changes the value of the parameter, *this change is not reflected globally or in the calling function*.
>
> If you pass an object (i.e. a non-primitive value, such as Array or a user-defined object) as >a parameter and the function changes the object's properties, *that change is visible outside the function*

Comment: Please note that W3Schools [isn't always the best resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com). We usually prefer to link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: Thanks @lvar, I will remember this in future...